# How is the number of states in a Turing machine bounded?

Tags: terminology, turing-machines, computation-models

The definition of Turing machine says that the number of states is finite. However, I do not get how this can be true. Is the number of states in a Turing machine actually not fixed, that is not bounded? If not, can anyone explain how this is possible?

Comment: It is better if you ask your professor. This is a very basic concept. Just note that the computation state (what is there on the tape and the head position) is not the same as the state in the transition function which is described by a finite matrix). In the context of TM, state means transition function state, not the unbounded computational state.

Comment: Any *one* Turing machine has a fixed number of states, but it can be arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 7):

You seem to have misunderstood the definition of a Turing machine. The "state" refers not to the whole configuration of the machine (tape contents, position of the head, etc.) but to the state of the finite automaton that controls the tape head.  The automaton has a finite number of states by definition.

Answer (score 5):

The tape isn't part of the machine, so the tape contents aren't part of the machine's internal state. Of course (a finite fragment of) the tape content *is* part of the state of a *computation* conducted with the machine: its *configuration*.

The configuration is the machine's "external" state: the state of the machine executing a particular process within its environment; the state of that process.

The same distinction can be made for any other machine, e.g.

- A car: its position on a map isn't part of the internal state of a car, but it is part of e.g. its state within a navigation application.
- You: where you are isn't part of your internal state, but it is part of your state when describing an activity in which your whereabouts play a role.
- A copier: paper in its input and output trays can be regarded as not being part of the machine's internal state (this is a matter of choice), but it is definitely part of the state when describing how the machine works.